# data not loaded in charts (published using custom vsts extensions )

Tags: javascript, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Iam adding a chart in build results summary tab. i have given the contribution a a unique id and registered a handler for that id using VSS.Register() which will create my chart.
Iam getting no data in the charts.and no errors as well.
this is from the default vsts extension samples with litle to no modification but still its not working.

I suspect something might be wrong with the registration of handler to the contributionid but i have tried all the possible ways of doing it.
as can be seen with multiple register calls .

Kindly suggest what might be going wrong here

Below is  my vss-extension.json,charts.js and SimplePieChart.html.

```
{
"manifestVersion": 1,
"id": "BuildSummary",
"version": "1.2.2",
"name": "Pie Charts in Build Tab",
"publisher": "uniqueidguid",
"targets": [
    {
        "id": "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services"
    }
],
"icons": {
    "default": "img/logo.png"
},
"demands": ["contribution/ms.vss-dashboards-web.widget-sdk-version-2", "contribution/ms.vss-web.charts-service"],
"contributions": [
   {
        "id": "metrics",
        "type": "ms.vss-build-web.build-results-section",
        "description": "build results view",
        "targets": [
            "ms.vss-build-web.build-results-summary-tab",
        ],
        "properties": {
            "name": "Metrics Tab",
            "catalogIconUrl": "img/CatalogIcon.png",
            "description": "A simple pie chart widget with no configuration and hard-coded data.",
             "uri": "SimplePieChart.html"
        }
    }
],
"files": [
    {
        "path": "SimplePieChart.html",
        "addressable": true
    },
    {
        "path": "sdk/scripts/VSS.SDK.min.js",
        "addressable": true
    },
    {
        "path": "img",
        "addressable": true
    },
    {
        "path": "scripts",
        "addressable": true
    }
],
"scopes": [
]}
```

```js
VSS.init({
        explicitNotifyLoaded: true,
        usePlatformStyles: true,
        usePlatformScripts: true 
    });

var $container = $('#Chart-Container');
var chartOptions = { 
    "hostOptions": { 
        "height": "290", 
        "width": "300"
    },

    "chartType": "pie",
    "series": [{
        "data": [11, 4, 3, 1]
    }],
    "xAxis": { 
        "labelValues": ["Design", "On Deck", "Completed", "Development"] 
    }, 
    "specializedOptions": {
        "showLabels": "true",
        "size": 200
    } 
};
var chartHandler= (WidgetHelpers, Services)=> {
            return Services.ChartsService.getService().then((chartService)=>{
                chartService.createChart($container, chartOptions);
                return WidgetHelpers.WidgetStatusHelper.Success();
            });
}

VSS.require([
        "TFS/Dashboards/WidgetHelpers", 
        "Charts/Services"
        ],
     (WidgetHelpers, Services) =>  {
        WidgetHelpers.IncludeWidgetStyles();
        VSS.ready(()=>{

        VSS.register("uniqueidguid.BuildSummary.metrics", () => { 
         return {
             load : chartHandler
        });

        VSS.register(VSS.getContribution().id, () =>{ 
         return {
             load : chartHandler
        });

        VSS.register("metrics",() =>{ 
         return {
             load:chartHandler
         }
        });

    VSS.notifyLoadSucceeded();
        });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="sdk/scripts/VSS.SDK.min.js"></script>
    <script   src="scripts/charts.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="widget">
        <h2 class="title">Chart Widget</h2>
        <div id="Chart-Container"></div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Did you get any error during your publish? Which command you are using to do the publish?

Comment: No error during publish or during installation and in the logs.

Comment: I  think it might be due contribution target and type which must be  ms.vss.web.widget-catalog and ms.vss.web.widget while using charts.but how do I specify that the chart should load in build summary tab. Is it possible? Is there a way to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The VSS.register method in the charts sample is used to register the function to the widget. In build summary tab, you just need to call the function to create the chart service directly.

Code Sample for your reference:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="bower_components/vss-web-extension-sdk/lib/VSS.SDK.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
VSS.init({
        explicitNotifyLoaded: true,
        usePlatformStyles: true 
    });

VSS.require([
        "Charts/Services"
        ],
        function (Services) {
        VSS.ready(function () { 
             Services.ChartsService.getService().then(function(chartService){
                    var $container = $('#Chart-Container');
                    var chartOptions = { 
                        "hostOptions": { 
                            "height": "350", 
                            "width": "300"
                        },
                        "chartType": "pie",
                        "series": [{
                            "data": [11, 4, 3, 1]
                        }],
                        "xAxis": { 
                            "labelValues": ["Design", "On Deck", "Completed", "Development"] 
                        }, 
                        "specializedOptions": {
                            "showLabels": "true",
                            "size": 200
                        } 
                    };
                    chartService.createChart($container, chartOptions);
                });
                }        
            );
    VSS.notifyLoadSucceeded();
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="widget">
        <h2 class="title">Chart Widget</h2>
        <div id="Chart-Container"></div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

The result:
[image]